# Python cv2 webcam only display solid cyan color

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I've been stuck here for hours and have no idea why it only displays solid cyan color, I've tried both my PC and my laptop, and the outcome are just the same.

[image: 1]

Here's my code:

```
import cv2 

webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret, frame = webcam.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow("Title", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            break
webcam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. The solid cyan image is from Droidcam. So, all I have to do is connect to my phone camera and now I am able to get the image from it.